# Best way to read excel data into C# 2020? Office version 18 seems not to be supported

Tags: c#, excel, office365, version

I'm trying to read data from an excel file (.xlsx, .xlsm, etc.) into C# and I feel like it should be simple. The most popular way I see is using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` but when I run it I receive this error (keys x'd out)

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxx'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'office, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

from this line of code

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
```

and I believe it's because it's checking for office version 15.0 but I have version 18.2. So I went to nuget to get a newer version of the package with no luck this is the newest version. Any advice on how I can fix this? I don't have office version 15 on my pc and I'm not certain I can get it. Is there something I'm doing wrong here or is there a different method advised? I feel like this would be a pretty common need any help is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

At work, always using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` has always been discouraged as it needs office installed for many activities. This is problematic especially when you host your application on a server and there you don't want to install the entire user office version or even some of the cumbersome microsoft office (`interop`) libraries themselves required.
I am used to working with external libraries like `EPPlus`, `smart xls`, etc., which are doing really well in this role, starting with the develop-friendly interface to the size of the packages.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will look into these, agreed this didn't seem like best way but it seemed most popular. Thanks!